# Solve a contour integral: $\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^2+1}{z(16z^2+1)}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am trying to solve a contour integral: $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^2+1}{z(16z^2+1)}$$

Where $\gamma$ is the postivley oriented circular contour of radius 1/4 about the point 1.

My attempt at the solution:

$\frac{z^2+1}{z(16z^2+1)}$ has singularitites at $z=0$ and $z= +i1/4$ and $z=-i1/4$

I am trying to see if the poles are insider countour, however i don't know how to releate complex poles to real adius.

Comment: The contour can be parametrized by $\gamma (t) = \frac{e^{it}}{4} +1, t \in [0, 2\pi)$ but to see if any of the poles are within a radius 1/4 of 1, you can just see if $|1-z_0| < 1/4$ or not for $z_0$ being the pole.

Comment: That circular contour consists of all complex numbers within a distance of 1/4 of $z=1$. The distance between one of the poles $z_0$ and $z=1$ is just $|1-z_0|$. That should be enough!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $:$ The integrand is holomorphic on and inside the contour because all the poles are lying outside the contour. What can you conclude from here?

Comment: Does that mean by cauchy's theorem the integral is zero

Comment: Yes indeed @leahforbes.

Answer (score 0):

The distance from any of the poles to $1$ is $\sqrt{1+1/16}>1/4$, and the distance from $0$ to $1$ is $1$, which is also greater than $1/4$. Therefore, your integral is equal to $0$.

Comment: The distance from the pole at $0$ to $1$ is just $1$ and from the other two to 1 are $\sqrt{1 + 1/16}$

Comment: Yes, I missed the pole at $0$ and, yes, it's $\sqrt{1+1/16}$. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: So is it correct to assume the integral is equal to zero

Comment: Yes. That's the reason I wrote “your integral is equal to $0$”.